# Flexbox direction column - column width same as second column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create 3 rows with equal width (based on the 2nd row).

First row: Text
Second row: Image
Third row: Text

The image width must not be greater than the real image width. But it's allowed to shrink (so it's not wider than the screen width - already got that).
The other rows (text rows) just should be the same width as the image. I tried my best with flexbox but dont seem to get it working.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="first">
                Text Text Text Text
            </div>

            <img class="second" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2012/08/24111405/stackoverflow-logo-700x467.png" />

            <div class="third">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
}

.first {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.second { /* image */
  align-self: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.third {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: green;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/djb7z2m3/7/

Is there another way or did I just miss anything? Tried alot like flex-basis/grow/shrink and align stuff but didn't get the result I'm expecting.

Comment: Kind of begs the question, why are you even using `flexbox` here at all? It appears redundant. I'm not saying it shouldn't be used here, but it doesn't seem to serve any practical use here.

Comment: I don't think you can as the content of the last div is always going to be wider than the image and therefore will push the parent div to be that wide too - best bet is to use js, unless all the max-widths of the images are going to be the same width - in that case just set your container to have a max width of the images width in pixels

Comment: The natural width of your image is 700px. Try adding `.content {max-width:700px;}

Comment: @Rawrplus Its not like I need to use flexbox here. Just thought it would be the most dynamic approach. How else would you do it without knowing the width of the image?

Comment: @enxaneta The image was just for demonstration. There are multiple images with different widths.

Comment: @DevInTrouble by using the image and setting the `width:` to `auto`? Potentially combining it with `calc()` if you want to do some further width calculations with it. Though as a web designer myself, I'd just strongly recommend setting one common max-width for the images and anything else will get cropped as an overflow. Or better yet, don't paste `<img>` directly, use `background:` instead and play around with the `background-size` and `background-position` property

Comment: @Rawrplus Yea `width: auto` with `max-width: 100%` does the right thing with my image, but the other two (text) rows won't be the same width as the image anyway. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Potentially `.content > * { flex-basis: 0; flex-grow: 1; }` could nicely utilize the fact it is in a flexbox,